# htaccess url rewrite bootstrap

Tags: php, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, redirect

Im looking to create a htaccess rewrite rule to push everything through a single file:

```
RewriteCond $1 !^(index\.php)
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.php/$1 [L]
```

Nice and simple.

What I'm struggling with is also redirecting none www. to www. whilst still keeping the above redirect rule working.

Please note that the host would be unknown as multiple domains/site will be pushed through this htaccess.

Thanks!

Following the comments

```
Options   FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond $1 !^(index\.php)
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.php/$1 [L]

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\.
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.%{HTTP_HOST}/$1 [R=301,L]
```

Does work in redirecting none www to www but doesn pull through the rest of the url:

test.com/2 should redirect to www.test.com/2 and be redirected through to the index.php, but its being redirected to www.test.com.

Answer (score 1):

Add below your above rules these lines:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\.
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.%{HTTP_HOST}/$1 [R=301,L]
```

Comment: If I do that then: test.com/2 redirects to www.test.com not www.test.com/2